# how to echo an onlick function in php

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

Hi I am using php and my delete button is in a loop because the list is in a form of a table and each row has an individual delete button. I need to make a confirmation if the user really wants to delete an item. I tried using this code `onclick="return confirm('You sure')"` It is working in a normal html situation but if i echo it out in PHP it doesnt work. what is the correct format.

my code

```
foreach($people as $row){

        echo "<form action=".base_url()."some_controller/hideSingleApp_idx method=post>     
        echo "<td>".$row->description."</td>";
        echo "<td><input type=image src=".base_url()."hidebutton_white.png height=17 width=17 onclick='return confirm(You sure?)'/><br></td></form>";
```

Comment: What do you mean by *doesnt work* ? have you ever checked your PHP syntax?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($people as $row){
    echo "<form action=".base_url()."some_controller/hideSingleApp_idx method=post>";     
    echo "<td>".$row->description."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type=image src=".base_url()."hidebutton_white.png height=17 width=17 onclick='return confirm(\"You sure nigga?\")'/><br></td></form>";
```

Comment: still OP will get `syntax error` , first echo has error.

Answer (score 1):

And your first `echo` has syntax error. add quote and semicolon at the end.

```
echo "<form action=".base_url()."some_controller/hideSingleApp_idx method=post>";
```

wrap it in quotes, this will work

```
  echo "<td><input type=image src=".base_url()."hidebutton_white.png height=17 width=17 onclick='return confirm(\"You sure nigga?\");'/><br></td></form>";
```

Comment: you have to first prevent default behavior of `input [type=image]` with javascript.